# drawing directly to canvas and creating layout using java code

Tags: java, android, canvas, surfaceview

[I was following the series on canvas drawing](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ziMD-VvZRg4&list=PLQRwIPDHLeOKkI3qYpG7vRoDMGijqeSOO&index=10) , and at `1:27` , the author quotes: "**A class responsible for managing and drawing the layout has to extend the SurfaceView and also needs to implement a thread, so we're going to implement the `Runnable` interface**"

The author is implementing a direct draw to canvas without using xml files using `java` code only and uses a `java` class instead of `xml`. He defines the layout in `java` as:

```
public class Activity_Animation002_Layout extends SurfaceView implements Runnable{

    Thread thread = null;

    public Activity_Animation002_Layout(Context context){
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(CanDraw){
        //TODO- carry out drawing....
     }
    }
    //some more code to follow
}
```

The associated activity file has code like this:

```
public class AnimationActivity002 extends Activity{
    Activity_Animation002_Layout animation002_LayoutView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        animation002_LayoutView = new Activity_Animation002_Layout(this);
        setContentView(animation002_LayoutView);
    }
}
```

Is this drawing technique outdated? I mean I have search high and low, and tried to google, checked the pages like: [Custom Drawing](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing), [Canvas Drawing](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas), [Layouts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout), [Layout Resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource) , [SurfaceView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView) but none of them so much as even extend a `surfaceView`. **Where can I find this in the documentation?** *But if this is an outdated technique or something*, then what is the new way of doing the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

1. You can do this easier, but the thing is about what **you really want to achieve here**. You can pretty much do the drawing simply in a `View` class in its `onDraw(Canvas)`.
2. `SurfaceView` is a special kind of View. With a `SurfaceView` you can draw on another Thread (not the UI thread). Thats why your class has to implement `Runnable` - you have to pass it to a Thread. An example:

   - `View` draws on UI Thread so if you try to animate something in that View and do some stuff on UI Thread (for example scroll through a layout) it will be laggy
   - `SurfaceView` draws on another Thread so you can freely animate something and also scroll, click things etc with no lags.
3. `SurfaceView` might be also used for games (where a lot is happening on the screen), but i wouldn't say it is heavily used for that nowadays. But a fact is that it is possible to make some dodgy games based on `SurfaceView`, or something like flappy bird

**To summarize:**

- I don't think it is an outdated technique, more like its not commonly used, because you would use it in a specific situation, where you need to draw something (e.g simple animation) without freezing the UI Thread
- You can also draw in a simple `View` class, but its ok only if you're not planning to do other actions with the UI. (or if the drawing isn't long). **Things from the video you mentioned** could be done in a simple `View`, because there is not much happening there - you just draw the images once and thats it. I even remember i've done a card game entirely with a `View` class, where you dragged cards to the middle to play.

Comment: do you know where in the documentation is this the technique? He does point to the link but it is placed elsewhere

Comment: I don't think you can find a `documentation` for the technique. In general `techniques` don't have documentations really, because there are so many ways and ideas to achieve the same thing. There are of course basic guidelines or good practises on certain things.
In my opinion all you can do in that matter is to search for tutorials and examples that  would enlighten you in some way. And of course find out if it is really what you need for the project you want to make. (If you want to make a game there are a plenty of libraries that make it easier, e.g LIbGDX (free) or Unity (paid))